# mac + tableau + kerbores + hive + cloudera gssMinor code may provide more information (No credentials found with supported encryption type

Tags: macos, hive, tableau-api, cloudera

I am unable to connect to tableau using the cloudera hive driver using kerberos authentication, even after configuring the kerb5.conf with appropriate info.

Issue is with the encryption property used in the /etc/krb5.conf file. I have removed the following lines before made it work.

```
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac
```

Comment: issue  is with the encryption property used in the /etc/krb5.conf file. i have removed the following lines before made it work. 
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac

Comment: Please [edit] details into your question, don't post them as comments.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the encryption property used in the /etc/krb5.conf file. I have removed the following lines before made it work.

```
default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
permitted_enctypes = rc4-hmac
```

the following is the complete (sudo) contents of  /etc/krb5.conf file.

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = NA.CORP.xxx.com
dns_lookup_kdc = true
dns_lookup_realm = false
ticket_lifetime = 86400
renew_lifetime = 604800
forwardable = true

udp_preference_limit = 1
kdc_timeout = 3000
[realms]
NA.xxx.COM = {
kdc = xxx.com
admin_server = xxx1.com
}
default_cc_type = FILE
default_ccache_name = FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_501
[domain_realm]
```